How to get the success status of moveit trajectory execution?
I am using kuka lbr iiwa14 robot and controlling it with ros2 humble using this driver (https://github.com/lbr-stack/lbr_fri_ros2_stack). I can chose the predefined pose and the robot moves. However, I want to publish the trajectory execution status in  another topic. How can I access the trajectory execution status? (For example, "Executed" in the motion planning window.)
